# Run NodeJs express app on base url with nginx app

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, proxy

#### Scenario

I have a php app. This app runs on say `abc.com`. It uses a nginx server.
Now I created a new app, a NodeJS express one. This I need to be deployed on `abc.com/nodeApp` (not `abc.com/nodeApp/`)

#### What I did

In the nginx config of `abc.com`, I wrote a config to proxy the traffic to the Node server. Here is the nginx config.

```
  location = /nodeApp {
    proxy_pass http://$nodeApp;
    include proxy_params;
  }

  location /nodeApp/ {
    # remove all trailing slash
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    proxy_pass http://$nodeApp;
    include proxy_params;
  }
```

#### Problem

Now, on hitting `abc.com/nodeApp`, it takes me to the nodeJs server. But the server is giving 

`CANNOT GET /nodeApp`

So the nodeJs server is expecting the traffic on `/` and not on `/nodeApp`.
How can i make the server to have a base url. Here is my nodeJs file.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var config = require('./config/config');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));

var port = process.env.PORT || config.serverPort;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding a trailing `/` to the `proxy_path` directive, you will map `/nodeapp` to `/` upstream.

```
location = /nodeApp {
    proxy_pass http://$nodeApp/;
    include proxy_params;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.